# How to inspect about the privacy setting of a given user's birthday, friends on facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy

How can we inspect whether the facebook profile privacy setting for a given user's birthday, friends, family is public, friends or custom....

I am able to get the privacy setting for user's photos, videos and posts whether they are pubclic, friends or custom. But how can i do it for user's personal info like birthday, family etc.

Please guide me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API which will return this sort of information.
If your app can, from the perspective of a given user, see the information, that should be enough for your purposes, no? If you can't see a particular field, the user whose access token you're using can't see it or it's not present.